# How to use different base image names for multi-architecture builds with docker buildx?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The base images I need to build with don't support multi-architecture and are located in different repositories, such as `test:1.0` and `test-arm64:1.0`. Is there any way to use

```
docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64,linux/arm64
```

as usual in this scenario?